# Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference

Tags: javascript, firebase, vuejs2

I use firebasestore 9, in vue2 project and face to this error "Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore"

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'

import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  ////configg
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const dbase = getFirestore(app)
console.log(dbase)
export default{dbase }
```

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <NavBar></NavBar>
    <router-view></router-view>
    <FooterPage></FooterPage>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';
import dbase from '@/firebase/index'
import NavBar from './components/NavBar.vue';
import FooterPage from './components/FooterPage.vue';

export default {
  components: { NavBar, FooterPage },
  methods: {
    async getdata() {
       console.log(dbase)
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(dbase, "Menus"));
      
        console.log(querySnapshot);
      
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(dbase)
    this.getdata()
  }
}
</script>
```

how can I solve this eror and get data from firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you export only one value in your `index` file, just export as follows:

```
export default dbase;
```

If you want to continue exporting it as a list (for example because you are going to add some more Firebase services) do as follows:

```
export { dbase };
```

and possibly later (for example):

```
export { dbase, auth };
```

See this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) for more details.